# __free_pages - multiple execution

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu

I have traced `__free_pages` routine at `mm/page_alloc.c` and realized that there is a multiple execution with the same `page *` value. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

`page`s are reference-counted in the kernel. `__free_pages` decrements that count and when `_count` reaches 0, it then adds the page to the free list: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L2907

So, if there are `k` references to your page, you'll have to call `__free_pages` `k` times to actually free the page.